# about linux IO performance

Tags: java, linux, performance, io

I wrote a program to test IO performance in java useing FileChannel. Write data and call force(false) immediately. My Linux server has 12 ssd hard drives, sda~sdl, and I test writing data to different hard drive, the performance varies widely, and I don't know why?

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(args[0], "rw");
    int count = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int idx = count;
    FileChannel channel = aFile.getChannel();
    long time = 0;
    long bytes = 0;
    while (--idx > 0) {
        String newData = "New String to write to file..." + System.currentTimeMillis();
        String buff = "";
        for (int i = 0 ; i<100; i++) {
            buff += newData;
        }
        bytes += buff.length();
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(buff.length());
        buf.clear();
        buf.put(buff.getBytes());
        buf.flip();
        while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
            channel.write(buf);
        }
        long st = System.nanoTime();
        channel.force(false);
        long et = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("force time : " + (et - st));
        time += (et -st);
    }
    System.out.println("wirte " + count + " record, " + bytes + " bytes, force avg time : " + time/count);
}
```

Result like this:
sda: wirte 1000000 record, 4299995700 bytes, force avg time : 273480 ns
sdb: wirte 100000 record, 429995700 bytes, force avg time : 5868387 ns

The average time vary significantly.

Here is some IO monitor data.
sda:
[iostat data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76kAe.png)
sdb:
[iostat data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv5Ab.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what you see as the problem? There doesn't appear to be enough information to draw any conclusions. 0.005 seconds variation doesn't mean much for disk IO unless it is hightly reproducible.  I assume the drives are all the same except `sda` also have the operating system on it?

Comment: Note: when you write to a file for a benchmark, you can't need to create dummy data (unless the data will be compressed) A file full of zero bytes is the same as one containing random data.

Comment: Are all these disks the same model of drive on the same controller with the same file system type? BTW even 72 MB/s doesn't sound very high for an SSD. I would be looking for 400 - 500 MB/s

Comment: I would start by writing blocks of well over 4 KB e.g. 256 KB or 2 MB.

Comment: All the hard drives are the same model，ext3 file system，I don't know why the sda's force latency is much lower.

Comment: I assume it's because the disk is used for other things such as the OS and it doesn't buffer as much writes so there is less writes unwritten when you come to do the force sync. It doesn't mean for example there is any difference in performance.

Comment: os is installed in sda.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start by measure your SSD disks performance using some standard tool like [fio](http://freecode.com/projects/fio).

Then you can test your utility again using numbers from fio output.

Looks like you are writing into the Linux write cache so that can explain your results :)